# laravel parse large xml file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, laravel

```
        $app = new Container;
        $document = new OrchestraDocument($app);
        $reader = new OrchestraReader($document);
        $xml = $reader->load($path);
        $xml1 = simplexml_load_file($path);
      //  print_r($xml1);
        $json = json_encode($xml1);
        $array = json_decode($json, true);
        $clien =$array['cliente'];
             //controll empty value
            $clien = array_map(function($i) {
                $i['indirizzo'] = empty($i['indirizzo']) ? '' : $i['indirizzo'];
                $i['cap'] = empty($i['cap']) ? '' : $i['cap'];
                $i['citta'] = empty($i['citta']) ? '' : $i['citta'];
                $i['prov'] = empty($i['prov']) ? '' : $i['prov'];
                $i['piva'] = empty($i['piva']) ? '' : $i['piva'];
                $i['cfisc'] = empty($i['cfisc']) ? '' : $i['cfisc'];
                $i['luogo_nasc'] = empty($i['luogo_nasc']) ? '' : $i['luogo_nasc'];
                $i['data_nasc'] = empty($i['data_nasc']) ? '' : $i['data_nasc'];
                $i['sesso'] = empty($i['sesso']) ? '' : $i['sesso'];
                $i['tele'] = empty($i['tele']) ? '' : $i['tele'];
                $i['mail'] = empty($i['mail']) ? '' : $i['mail'];
                $i['cell'] = empty($i['cell']) ? '' : $i['cell'];
                $i['cod_card'] = empty($i['cod_card']) ? '' : $i['cod_card'];
                $i['cod_card1'] = empty($i['cod_card1']) ? '' : $i['cod_card1'];
                $i['punti_card'] = empty($i['punti_card']) ? '' : $i['punti_card'];
                return $i;
            }, $clien);
            $collection = collect($clien);
            $collection1 = $collection->chunk(500);
```

i'm try to import a large xml file into my mysql database.
i'm load my xml file into object, i'm tranform this object into array, i'm control the empty value, and ok.
Now because i have a large query i tranform my array in laravel collection and chunk for isert 500 records at a time, but now i have a new object $collection1. How i enter the query? i have to trasform again in array?

```
           for($i=0;$i<count($collection1);$i++) {
              var_dump($collection1[$i]);
                $collection1[$i]= stdToArray;
                    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
                    DB::table('clientis')->insert($collection1[$i]);
               foreach( $collection1[$i] as $k=>$v){
                var_dump($v);
                }
            }
```

thi code don't work

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you don't need to create a collection. You can just [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) the data:

```
/*
$collection = collect($clien);
$collection1 = $collection->chunk(500);
*/
$collection = array_chunk($clien, 500, true);
```

Comment: ok work fine but my cycle is interrupt after one loop this is my code don't work                  for($i=0;$i<count($collection);$i++)
                {
                        var_dump($collection[$i]);
                        $array_clienti = $collection[$i];
                        DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
   DB::table('clientis')->insert($array_clienti);
    dd('Insert Recorded successfully.');
                }   @Richard Parnaby-King